# Python map emptied after using tuple or iteration

Tags: python, tuples

The following code does not print anything from the `for` loop; it only prints the result of the `tuple`. This is very unintuitive because I haven't explicitly modified the `cheapest` map, yet it behaves as if it is empty after calling `tuple`.

So, what's going on?

```
store1 = [10.00, 11.00, 12.34, 2.34]
store2 = [9.00, 11.10, 12.34, 2.01]
cheapest = map(min, store1, store2)

print(tuple(cheapest))

for v in cheapest: 
    print(v)
```

Expected output:

```
(9.0, 11.0, 12.34, 2.01)
9.0
11.0
12.34
2.01
```

Actual output:

```
(9.0, 11.0, 12.34, 2.01)
```

If I run the `for` loop first, then the behavior is reversed: the `for` loop prints the values from the `cheapest` map and the `print(tuple(cheapest))` result is empty as in:

Actual output (order reversed):

```
9.0
11.0
12.34
2.01
()
```

Comment: It's not emptied so much as that iterator is just consumed to create the tuple, that's how it gets data. If you want to preserve it, consider `list(map(...))`

Comment: So... in Java `map` is a data structure, but in Python it's just an iterator? *oof*

Comment: It's just how Python rolls. This way if you didn't need all of the results, it wouldn't bother computing them, which is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @tadman Makes sense! Just need to rewire my brain then. :)

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark saved; that's probably better than other dupe targets I might have found for the general problem (which also commonly comes up with file iterators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When learning Python you'll need to pay close attention to the return type of various functions, as many, like [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), actually return an iterator<sup>1</sup>.

While an iterator can be efficient as it is only evaluated if necessary, it can lead to confusion like this where your data is suddenly "gone".

If you need to capture that result before using it in multiple locations, convert it into a more permanent form, like:

```
cheapest = list(map(min, store1, store2))
```

Where that can still be used in a `for` since it's iterable.

---

<sup>1</sup> In Ruby this is like `map { ... }.lazy` being enabled by default. In Rust it's very similar to Python, a `map()` must be captured with `collect()` before it's anything other than an iterator. If you're used to things like JavaScript where it just dumps out an array, it'll require a bit of re-learning.